# What information can we access from the client?

Tags: javascript, data-mining, data-retrieval

I'm trying to compile a list of information that is accessible via javascript such as:

- Geo-location
- IP address
- Browser software
- Exit location
- Entrance location

I understand that a user can alter any of this information and that it's reliability is purely trust related, but I am still interested in what other information can be mined from the client.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Don't forget about

- Screen Size
- Allowed Cookies
- Allowed Java
- Mobile or Desktop
- Language

And here is useful link with data-mining demo:

http://www.alanwood.net/demos/browserinfo.html

Comment: Thank's this is some useful information, notice some of the information it get's about me is a bit off like my max screen resolution being less than my current resolution but it's close enough.

Comment: You probably can't get precise informations using this method.

Comment: client operating system

Answer (score 108):

Here is most of the information:

```
var info={

    timeOpened:new Date(),
    timezone:(new Date()).getTimezoneOffset()/60,

    pageon(){return window.location.pathname},
    referrer(){return document.referrer},
    previousSites(){return history.length},

    browserName(){return navigator.appName},
    browserEngine(){return navigator.product},
    browserVersion1a(){return navigator.appVersion},
    browserVersion1b(){return navigator.userAgent},
    browserLanguage(){return navigator.language},
    browserOnline(){return navigator.onLine},
    browserPlatform(){return navigator.platform},
    javaEnabled(){return navigator.javaEnabled()},
    dataCookiesEnabled(){return navigator.cookieEnabled},
    dataCookies1(){return document.cookie},
    dataCookies2(){return decodeURIComponent(document.cookie.split(";"))},
    dataStorage(){return localStorage},

    sizeScreenW(){return screen.width},
    sizeScreenH(){return screen.height},
    sizeDocW(){return document.width},
    sizeDocH(){return document.height},
    sizeInW(){return innerWidth},
    sizeInH(){return innerHeight},
    sizeAvailW(){return screen.availWidth},
    sizeAvailH(){return screen.availHeight},
    scrColorDepth(){return screen.colorDepth},
    scrPixelDepth(){return screen.pixelDepth},


    latitude(){return position.coords.latitude},
    longitude(){return position.coords.longitude},
    accuracy(){return position.coords.accuracy},
    altitude(){return position.coords.altitude},
    altitudeAccuracy(){return position.coords.altitudeAccuracy},
    heading(){return position.coords.heading},
    speed(){return position.coords.speed},
    timestamp(){return position.timestamp},


    };
```

Comment: I heard that's possible to get battery info from mobile device, and some website, such hotel reservation websites, increase their prices when your battery is near empty.

Comment: battery level is only accessible on some browsers, iOS 9 it's not available

Comment: @BelowtheRadar a reference would be nice

Comment: `position` is undefined.

Comment: @BelowtheRadar https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Battery_Status_API

Comment: @PedroLobito Seems like Firefox and Safari are the only modern browsers that block "spoofing" on battery status https://groups.google.com/g/mozilla.dev.platform/c/5U8NHoUY-1k/m/9ybyzQIYCAAJ
Another reason why I prefer FF over all

Comment: Navigator.appName is depcreated and returns always Netscape. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/appName. The same counts for navigator.product (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/product), navigator.appVersion (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/appVersion). One can not rely on information gathered by these properties.

Answer (score 8):

visitor.js is a javascript library that provides information about the client.

Including:

1. Continent, Country and city
2. Date of last visit
3. Referring website or search engine (including search term)
4. Time spent on the website
5. Browser and operating system
6. IP Address
7. Language
8. Browser
9. OS
10. Screen size

And more.

http://www.visitorjs.com/

Visitorjs might be very handy, it's not free however.