# Firefox presentation api support

Tags: firefox, multiple-monitors, presentation-api

As a result of the dicussion on

[What needs to be done to make multiple screen support for Javascript happen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57295847/what-needs-to-be-done-to-make-multiple-screen-support-for-javascript-happen)

i am looking into the state of affairs with Firefox and found this issue

- https://github.com/mozilla/standards-positions/issues/180

As it looks it's possible to use the API on Firefox. I'd like to test this.

**What environment would be needed for this to show an example?**