# Send tab to second screen from javascript

Tags: browser

Can you control output of new tab to second screen via javascript? Like PowerPoint start slide show starts on second screen. Perhaps via webassembly?

Comment: This question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16363474/window-open-on-a-multi-monitor-dual-monitor-system-where-does-window-pop-up might be helpful

Comment: And this one also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57295847/what-needs-to-be-done-to-make-multiple-screen-support-for-javascript-happen/57303963#57303963 talking about the `Presentation API`